# Get beginning of the day by given date in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an todo application and some tasks have deadlines. If deadline is bigger or equal than current date, I want to display them. However, there is a local datetime problem i believe.

This is the current date using 'print(Date())':
2021-07-27 18:53:03 +0000

This is the beginning of that date using 'print(Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()))':
2021-07-26 21:00:00 +0000

As you see, 27th day becomes 26th. I tried timezone operations also. It seems true but day is still starting at 21.00

When I convert them as string and print them, it is ok it show the expected results but without string type it becomes like above. Because of I want to get the bigger or equal days compared to current date , string solution is not working. It is the 27th of day but because of date object it is shown as 26th day and my app showing yesterdays tasks etc.

Can you provide a help for me?

Thanks

Comment: Are you testing this in a timezone that is 3 hours different than GMT?

Comment: Yes My timezone is GMT +3. When I print that date object as string using date formatter it is giving the true results

Comment: `print` doesn't respect the timezone when printing. Is your question how to `print` the value for your timezone, then?

Comment: My question is not about print it was just for clarification. I want to control a date is greater or equal than current date  ( as day like 27th day). But because of my localized date is different than GMT, i cant check correctly.  I should compare localized date objects, not GMT objects

Comment: a Date has no timezone it is just a point in time. If you would like to print your date using the current locale just print `date.description(with: .current)`

Comment: In other words your date is correct.